# Where exactly is the following process incorrect to yield an impossible answer

Tags: trigonometry, proof-verification, inverse, fake-proofs

I was playing with my calculator and found some strange phenomena.

$\cos(\tan(\tan(\tan(\pi/4)))) = 0.75686700166$

[Verify here](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=cos%28tan%28tan%28tan%2845%29%29%29%29&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#channel=fs&q=cos%28tan%28tan%28tan%28pi/4%29%29%29%29)

Now when we apply some inverses, then

$\tan(\tan(\tan(\pi/4))) = \arccos(0.75686700166)$

$or, \tan(\tan(\tan(\pi/4))) = 0.712290287$

[Verify here](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=cos%28tan%28tan%28tan%2845%29%29%29%29&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=arccos%280.75686700166%29)

Similarly, applying further `arctan`

$\tan(\pi/4) = 0.554220248 $

$or, 1 = 0.5544220248$

Now, this conclusion is impossible, so something we assumed must be incorrect! Method of contradiction. But in this case, which step would be considered incorrect or inaccuarate?

Is it just because of the precision of numbers? Or is there something else i am missing here?

Comment: Careful, periodic functions aren't 1-to-1 so they don't have true inverses. You need an injective function for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $\tan(\tan(\tan(\frac{\pi}4)))= 74.686$

$\cos (74.686)= 0.757$ as you have

$\arccos (0.757) = 0.619$

The multiple tan function takes you out of the interval $[0,2\pi)$

Comment: Thanks. Can you please elaborate! (esp. the last statement).

Comment: $\cos$ is a periodic function and $\arccos$ always returns the result in the first period (between $0$ and $\pi$). If you start with a number outside this interval (say, $74.686$) and plug it into $\cos$, the $\arccos$ will not return the same number back, but will find a solution in the first period.

Comment: @orion thanks! Got this now. So, the interval actually is between 0 to 3.141...